# Django: ImportError allauth.twitter: No module named twitter

Tags: django, django-allauth

I installed allauth but when I run manage.py syncdb I am getting the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError allauth.twitter: No module named twitter
```

Any ideas to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct path should be: `allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter` taking a fast look over the [code in github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth)

This is the path you need to pass to `INSTALLED_APPS` in case you need it

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    ...
)
```

Or in your `import` like this:

```
import allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where should I provide the path?